# Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopePool::__construct()

Tags: magento2, rest-api, elasticsearch

After installing elasticsearch module, I am getting an error while accessing search api. Same module is working fine in a fresh magento. But it produces error in my existing project. I tried by disabling all other modules, but in vain.

```
Fatal Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Framework\\App\\Config\\ScopePool::__construct() must implement interface Magento\\Framework\\App\\Config\\Scope\\ReaderPoolInterface, instance of Smile\\ElasticsuiteCore\\Model\\Search\\Request\\RelevanceConfig\\ReaderPool given
```

Can anyone help with any help with this error message?

Comment: Clear the `var/generation` folder and refresh

Comment: I did this many times. But no use.

Comment: If this is 3rd party module, you should ask the vendor

Comment: delete all files of this module from system and then clear var/generation

Comment: delete all files of this module from system means? I cleared var/di, var/generation, var/view_preprocessed, var/page_cache